# How to load all items in listbox instead of just the visual ones

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, virtualization

How do I load all the items in listbox instead of just the ones showing? Basically, how do you turn off the virtualizing of a Listbox? I tried  but nothing worked.

```
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Black" BorderThickness="0" IsEnabled="False" ForceCursor="True">
                <ListBox.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="listBoxTransform" />
                </ListBox.RenderTransform>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel x:Name="wp" IsItemsHost="True" ItemHeight="244" ItemWidth="184" Width="1700">
                        </WrapPanel>                            
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Image}" x:Name="dtName">
                        <!-- The Image binding -->
                        <Image Width="170" Height="230" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: You do have VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"?  How do you know they are not loading?   Try taking out the RenderTransform.  Possibly you have a render lag not a load lag.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code (modified from yours)

```
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                  Background="Black" BorderThickness="0" IsEnabled="False"
                  ForceCursor="True">
            <ListBox.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="listBoxTransform" />
            </ListBox.RenderTransform>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel x:Name="wp" IsItemsHost="True" ItemHeight="244" ItemWidth="184" Width="1700">
                    </WrapPanel>                            
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Image}" x:Name="dtName">
                    <!-- The Image binding -->
                    <Image Width="170" Height="230" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I changed the VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing to False (as suggested in a previous answer) and I added the ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False", which negates the virtualization and also allows for a smooth scrolling if the items inside the ListBox are too big (instead of jumping from item to item, it goes by small steps).

Hope this solves your issue, regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Team}" 
                       ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource NameDataStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Oh, clever - other than the obvious True => False typo, this might work...wasn't aware that was an attached property.

Comment: That does not seem to work. I have updated my question with the source code of what I am trying to get working. Thanks

Comment: @user1585542 , as  JerKimball commented, set VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to override the `ItemsPanel` (specifically, providing a new `ItemsPanelTemplate`), as that is where the `VirtualizingStackPanel` is specified/used.

Something like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```